# JS - How to start from new line inside for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, newline

I am trying to print 6 random numbers after clicking a button. Then every time I click the button again, random numbers should start from new line however I do not know how. I tried everything and nothing works. I appreciate any help.

```js
        function fname() {
            for(i=1; i<=6; i++) {
                    number = number + Math.floor(Math.random() * 47 + 1) + "-";
                    var print = number + " GOOD LUCK!";
            }
            document.getElementById("total").value = print;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Let's ROLL!</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            input, button {display: block;}
        </style>
        <script>
        var number = "";
        function fname() {
            for(i=1; i<=6; i++) {
                    number = number + Math.floor(Math.random() * 47 + 1) + "-";
                    var print = number + " GOOD LUCK!";
            }
            document.getElementById("total").value = print;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <button onclick="fname()">ROLL!</button>
            <textarea id="total" rows="12" cols="50" readonly></textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of scope? `print` is being initialised *inside* the for loop then accessed outside.

Comment: @MTCoster, yes I made mistake by having almost all my code inside for loop. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% clear on where you wanted the breaks, but in a text area, a line break is `\n`.  If this was in an HTML element, you would use `<br />`.

```js
var number = "";

function fname() {
  for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    number = number + Math.floor(Math.random() * 47 + 1) + "-";
  }
  number = number + "\n";
  
  var print = number + "GOOD LUCK!";
  document.getElementById("total").value = print;
}
```

```css
 input,
 button {
   display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="fname()">ROLL!</button>
  <textarea id="total" rows="12" cols="50" readonly></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! I tried similar code by myself however I had everything inside the loop :) Now I see my mistake, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Add "\n".

I am assuming you want to concatenate the new text in the text area, so you should use += instead of =:

```
document.getElementById("total").value += print + "\n";
```

Comment: That'll precede the whole value with a newline.  You'd be better putting it after ;)

Comment: That's true - it would add an unnecessary line before everything else. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrays and `.join()` the numbers and lines together by their appropriate delimiters. This only inserts the characters between the elements. `\n` in a string renders a new line.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('roll');
var total = document.getElementById('total');

var rolls = [];

button.onclick = function() {
    var roll = [];
    for(var i=0; i<6; ++i) roll.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 47 + 1));
    rolls.push(roll.join('-'));
    total.value = rolls.join('\n') + "\nGOOD LUCK!";
}
```

```html
<button id="roll">ROLL!</button><br>
<textarea id="total" rows="12" cols="50" readonly></textarea>
```

Comment: This is interesting and I will definitely  try this. I am not able to give you rep because my own rep is to low. Thank you for answering!